# SQL - Nested query

Tags: sql

I have a table with Group IDs and Member IDs, where some groups have multiple Member IDs. I only want the count of those groups with more than one member. I am trying to do this with nested queries, but I need to use Group by and Having- which are not allowed. How can I rewrite this? In the example, only 2 groups have multiple members and I need to return 2 as the result of the query. Thanks for any advice!
EDIT: Apparently GROUP BY and HAVING are okay to use in SAS 9.4 inside a nested query. So please ignore the "not allowed".

```
select count * 
from (select count( groupID) as groupsize from dat_table
        group by  groupID
        having count(mem_id) >1
      ) a;
```

[image: Example Data]

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: What do you mean by "Group by and Having- which are not allowed"? Which database do not allow it?

Comment: I am using PROC SQL inside the SAS programming language

Comment: @user2450223 Could you explain statement from the question that says Group By And Having beeing not allowed and acceptance of the answer having both of them. Is it missleaading instruction in the question or you didn't see group by and having in the accepted answer? Or something elsse ...

Comment: @d r I was told that Group BY and Having would not run - I'm not a SQL programmer - I'm using Proc SQL from within the SAS statistical program. However, it actually did work!

Comment: (I didn't downvote) 1) You didn't tag your database, 2) you said group by and having not allowed, still you marked a reply containing both group by and having.

Comment: @Cetin Basoz Sorry about that. I was told that Group By and Having would not work. (I am using SAS). However, it does work! Maybe it is because I have a newer version of SAS.  Thanks for your efforts. I can still learn from your answer

Comment: Not a problem  for me. If you have phrased ıt like "wıth Group by and having I am not getting the desired result" versus "not allowed" then people (like me) would not skip reading your SQL containing Group By and Having :) You need to be a bit careful about those details on SO.

Comment: @CetinBasoz ok got it :) I am using statistical software (SAS 9.4) which can run SQL  but it is not a database in itself. So these nuances are new to me! Anyway, I have now learnt an alternative to GROUP BY! Thanks much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is you are adding the count in your nested query instead of this do like below. I have tested that query on SQL Server and its works let me know if you are using any other database.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS groupcountwithmultiplememers
FROM (
SELECT groupId
FROM dat_table
GROUP BY groupId
HAVING COUNT(mem_id) > 1
) AS a;
```

Instead of the count(*) in your query you need to use the group id

The inner subquery

SELECT groupId
FROM dat_table
GROUP BY groupId
HAVING COUNT(mem_id) > 1
selects the Group Ids that have more than one member id

Then based on that outer query calculate the count

Comment: Thanks! This works - but why does it fail with just COUNT(*) in the outer query? I am using SAS SQL

Comment: The count(*) gives you number of count instead of actual ids and on the top you are using that count(*) that's why not working.

Answer (score 1):

(I don't know in which database group by and having is not allowed)
You didn't tag your database, but this would work on most of the databases:

```
select count(group_id)
from 
(select group_id, memberId, row_number() over (partition by groupId order by MemberId) as rowNo
from myTable) tmp
where tmp.rowNo = 2;
```

Comment: partition is essentially 'GROUP BY'

Comment: 'so what' - bit passive aggressive there! The OP has ridiculous requirements of not using GROUP BY. "You mean the database he is using doesn't allow row_number() as well?" - TBH I would expect a RDBMS to implement GROUP BY long before row_number()  much like SQL Server did.